# Why does an unspecialised template win over a partially specialised one?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, sfinae, template-matching

I am trying to create a templated `can_stream` struct that inherits from
`std::false_type` or `std::true_type` depending on whether `operator<<` is defined for type `T`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int i;
};

std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& os, S const& s) {
    os << s.i << std::endl;
    return os;
};

struct R {
    int i;
};

template<
    typename T,
    typename Enable = void
> struct can_stream : std::false_type {
};

template<
    typename T
> struct can_stream< T, decltype( operator<<( std::declval< std::ostream& >(), std::declval< T const& >())) > : std::true_type {
};

int main() {
    std::cout << can_stream< int >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << can_stream<  S  >::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << can_stream<  R  >::value << std::endl;
}
```

I thought the above program would produce

```
  1
  1
  0
```

because:

- operator `<<` exists for both `int` and `S` (so `decltype(...)` is well formed).
- partially specialised template is a better match than the unspecialised template.

However, it produces:

```
  0
  0
  0
```

Why?

Comment: Prefer the expression form. `std::declval< std::ostream& >() << std::declval< T const& >()` - Some built-in types are implemented by `std` as members of `ostream`. If you want to detect those too, you can't assume the operator is not a member. The expression takes care of all that for you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> operator `<<` exists for both `int` and `S` (so `decltype(...)` is well formed).

But `decltype( operator<<( std::declval< std::ostream& >(), std::declval< T const& >()))` is `std::ostream&`, where the default value for `Enable` is `void`.

There isn't match.

You can try with

```
template<
    typename T // ........................................................................................VVVVVVVVV
> struct can_stream< T, decltype( operator<<( std::declval< std::ostream& >(), std::declval< T const& >()), void() ) > : std::true_type {
};
```

or, if you can use C++17, so `std::void_t`,

```
template<
    typename T // ......VVVVVVVVVVVV
> struct can_stream< T, std::void_t<decltype( operator<<( std::declval< std::ostream& >(), std::declval< T const& >()))> > : std::true_type {
};
```

This solve the problem with `S`, because for `S` there is an `operator<<()` function. But doesn't works for `int` because, for `int`, the operator isn't defined as function. So, for `int`, you have to simulate the use

```
template<
    typename T // ...........................................................VVVV
> struct can_stream< T, std::void_t<decltype( std::declval< std::ostream& >() << std::declval< T const& >() )> > : std::true_type {
};
```

See you if you prefer check the existence of a function `operator<<()` (but this doesn't works with `int` and other types with implicit operator `<<`) or if the operator `<<` is concretely usable.

Comment: this makes `can_stream<int>::value == false` (https://godbolt.org/z/98e3hq) , but perhaps thats a different question

Comment: `decltype(std::declval<std::ostream&>() << std::declval<T const&>(), void())` works for `int` too though

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 I think that's because the form of `operator <<`.  `std::declval< std::ostream& >() << std::declval< T const& >()` should makes it work

Comment: "_But_ `decltype( operator<<(...)` _is_ `std::ostream&`, _where the default value for Enable is void_."

I was assuming `= void` in `typename Enable = void` meant '_use type void if no type is specified explicitly_'. I did not realise the partial specialisation needed to have `Enable = void` in order to match.